# Uncorrect kernel buffer reading

Tags: opencl

I'm working on a project on the GPU for signal processing. It includes multiplications, additions and FFTs/IFFTs. The data set is quite huge, and the kernels that I've developed are 9 in total, the most complicated are obviously those for FFTs/IFFTs. I've got a problem that I really don't understand. It could be a race condition, but it seems strange to me and actually I'm not able to solve for it.

I do use a single queue, so every command is called respecting the order. The fact is that the project is, to speak easily, divided in two sections (I have to save computational time as much as I can, so I placed on the bottom only the vital commands, batching them as much as I could):

1) on the top I create the basics (platform, device, context, program, kernels, queue, work sizes and other stuffs). Moreover here I create SOME OF the pinned buffers (pointer to already stored data to be read and not changing during execution) and device buffers (pointer to null). Then I push to the different kernels only the arguments that do not change during execution (the most part of) using the command SetKernelArg;

2) on the bottom (while loop - if statements) I pack all the Enqueue commands (memory mapping, kernel execution, buffer copying in some cases) to speed up processing (batching). Here sometimes I have to redefine some of the kernel args (few, changed during execution) and I have to create THE REST OF the pinned buffers (few, related to changed data).

Running the project, I enqueue ten commands (memory mapping, kernel execution, buffer copying) and everything's fine. Every kernel uses the output of the previous kernel as one of the inputs. Moreover, some of them use pinned buffer (some created on the top, related to independent data, some created on the bottom during execution, related to recomputed data) and as additional constraint every command waits for the previous one to be finished (probably redundant since one queue is used) by means of the command wait list. Extrapolated some data to be used as following inputs, I run again another pack of the same commands on different kernels. The first two kernel executions work fine, data are good (the first one takes as one of the inputs one of the pinned buffers created on the top). Running the third kernel, there is a problem (race condition?) storing one of the pinned buffers (input, global memory) created on the top level on a private variable of the same type inside the kernel, as figured out inspecting data inside the kernel through the use of CodeXL debugger. In between there are just device buffers which act as output/input through each kernel. I'm asking myself why this problem shows up successively (on the third kernel execution) and not on the first one, since both use global pinned buffers (related to indipendent different data) created on the top level.

The fact is that, if I should read the input buffer content on the host before/after kernel execution, data correspond to the original values, so they are the same and ordered in the same way, indeed inside the kernel some of the values are different (real, everytime the same uncorrect values and everytime corresponding to the same work-item, no random values). Inside the kernel, I've tried using barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE) command, read_mem_fence(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE) command, but nothing solves it. On the host, the architecture is identical to the first part, with commands enqueued in order and synchronized additionally thorugh events.
Is this a race condition? And how could I fix it if events (on the host) and barriers/fences (in the kernel) do not solve the problem?

I'm very sorry for giving you probably an annoying description of the problem (and maybe a bit confusing) and unfortunately I can't share pieces of the code for privacy rules (and it could be too long since the host code is quite huge).

Regards to everybody

Marco

Comment: 1) I don't understand your problem. 2) CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE does not sync global work items, just local work items accesing global memory.

Comment: 1) a pinned buffer (CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR) is not correctly read inside the kernel, even if its data are correctly stored (as verified reading the buffer before/after kernel has been enqueued). The uncorrect values are everytime the same, finite, on the same work items, not random. Synch between kernels is enabled through events.                                          2) ok